# How to call log.error() from a service? Always gives "No such property: log for class: gi.mypackage.$UserServiceImplementation

Tags: grails

In Grails 3.3.8, using the new Grails services based on interfaces, my `UserService` is something like this:

```
interface IUserService {
    User get(Serializable id)
    List<User> list(Map args)
    Long count()
    void delete(Serializable id)
    User save(User user)
}

@Service(User)
@Transactional
abstract class UserService implements IUserService {
    @Override
    User save(User user) {
        log.error("mymessage")
}
```

When I call my `userService.save(user)` method, it can't resolve `log`. It works from the controller out of the box. How do I get a log instance into Grails services?

Error is:

> No such property: log for class: gi.mypackage.$UserServiceImplementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the docs section on [logger names](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#loggerName), services in `grails-app/services/` should have a `log` automatically injected. However, if your service is elsewhere, like `src/main/groovy/`, you need to add the [`@Slf4j`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/logging/Slf4j.html) annotation to your service class.

```
@Service(User)
@Transactional
@Slf4j
abstract class UserService implements IUserService {
    @Override
    User save(User user) {
        log.error("mymessage")
}
```

Comment: The service was created with grails generate-all, and it is in the right place, but log.error fails with the above error.I guess its a bug in grails 3.3.8.

Comment: the @Sl4j fixed the issue!